# Unable to get facebook oauth response in internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer-8, facebook-oauth

I have been trying to do a facebook oauth (scope is email), my authorization url is [this](https://facebook.com/dialog/oauth?redirect_uri=https://secesx02vm38.ca.com/siteminderagent/forms/oauthcb.fcc?SMQUERYDATA=Sample&response_type=code&client_id=118285828341628&scope=email&state=https://secesx02vm38.ca.com/siteminderagent/forms/oauth_ashish_facebook.fcc?SMQUERYDATA=-SM-MsRaZDsudf5YpQWhcPsd4CuUzCdbEhH0NQYqbjei5OIAdu3easUaR%252fyyiqLiM8BWju1uyKiKZpMtFEF6sRkIH60kVOav8gJHqnEuGAmPhQetVor6HJXjA7nFlsGYqKgu6DgmxYTJqzGHjGSylvKwbvIxIz6uT%252bWywh5Y31egA6WaFjn03D%252bCseoRZHRhQ6LV%252baK7lmXJ64pA%252f3%252fj5uohIb%252fQZF%252bsf92jKaHyURzKxEsHUwmkEhT4VcmX1SISu8fRaJ4Zxef%252fA2t9IrLdgQY8RK6l5zs8EX2bdQQvlTc59yHAwZkpqZZx55JPe1BC1FMgH5%252fZfTUvccWNNGfTt8mMiBH3fyKF862UFOjMWpdmVgO2DNnO65mG%252bB75%252fy3P91V%252fTJcpGMcZuzLx3%252fpwbbCFLQ2JTuquDL6BhPmX8Co7v3xprE2kE4e4BbfKr%252fl2YzSmXjFcpuOesl%252bXrs%252femNoGj1TK%252b8NWdmgX1DIdVdAd6BJvVrOM2LDdJKUEmMP%252b5RPitFxdSTvv3qDQD3R2bO9isf2%252be7DOUQsvBApWrfDRunvBaxyy1QUr67IUliAtng3V1esxrUVeHIc0EWxdA0XVQN1T48X9cTe5FXLHBZfRRZSaGlPPXIZ517ABAwd2q87dNm17pJ6Va4TlOhXnLFh97hzm%252fcYuWakPiaQ0s0zVTLK6pgtwoDVOtuUzw2H9SrtUpcJ5RH%252bP%252bM9h8h%252bXumlrZ1P%252fbaC1LXTjAHktXcYBN7iVZ2v0OBC4QvspbfL8kM5B&SMOAuth_application=smuserfbapp2)

When i open the authorization url in firefox, i get directed to the  [HTTPS facebook login page](https://www.facebook.com/login.php?skip_api_login=1&api_key=118285828341628&signed_next=1&next=https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?redirect_uri=https%253A%252F%252Fsecesx02vm38.ca.com%252Fsiteminderagent%252Fforms%252Foauthcb.fcc%253FSMQUERYDATA%253DSample&state=https%253A%252F%252Fsecesx02vm38.ca.com%252Fsiteminderagent%252Fforms%252Foauth_ashish_facebook.fcc%253FSMQUERYDATA%253D-SM-MsRaZDsudf5YpQWhcPsd4CuUzCdbEhH0NQYqbjei5OIAdu3easUaR%25252fyyiqLiM8BWju1uyKiKZpMtFEF6sRkIH60kVOav8gJHqnEuGAmPhQetVor6HJXjA7nFlsGYqKgu6DgmxYTJqzGHjGSylvKwbvIxIz6uT%25252bWywh5Y31egA6WaFjn03D%25252bCseoRZHRhQ6LV%25252baK7lmXJ64pA%25252f3%25252fj5uohIb%25252fQZF%25252bsf92jKaHyURzKxEsHUwmkEhT4VcmX1SISu8fRaJ4Zxef%25252fA2t9IrLdgQY8RK6l5zs8EX2bdQQvlTc59yHAwZkpqZZx55JPe1BC1FMgH5%25252fZfTUvccWNNGfTt8mMiBH3fyKF862UFOjMWpdmVgO2DNnO65mG%25252bB75%25252fy3P91V%25252fTJcpGMcZuzLx3%25252fpwbbCFLQ2JTuquDL6BhPmX8Co7v3xprE2kE4e4BbfKr%25252fl2YzSmXjFcpuOesl%25252bXrs%25252femNoGj1TK%25252b8NWdmgX1DIdVdAd6BJvVrOM2LDdJKUEmMP%25252b5RPitFxdSTvv3qDQD3R2bO9isf2%25252be7DOUQsvBApWrfDRunvBaxyy1QUr67IUliAtng3V1esxrUVeHIc0EWxdA0XVQN1T48X9cTe5FXLHBZfRRZSaGlPPXIZ517ABAwd2q87dNm17pJ6Va4TlOhXnLFh97hzm%25252fcYuWakPiaQ0s0zVTLK6pgtwoDVOtuUzw2H9SrtUpcJ5RH%25252bP%25252bM9h8h%25252bXumlrZ1P%25252fbaC1LXTjAHktXcYBN7iVZ2v0OBC4QvspbfL8kM5B%2526SMOAuth_application%253Dsmuserfbapp2&scope=email&response_type=code&client_id=118285828341628&ret=login&cancel_uri=https://secesx02vm38.ca.com/siteminderagent/forms/oauthcb.fcc?SMQUERYDATA=Sample&error=access_denied&error_code=200&error_description=Permissions%2berror&error_reason=user_denied&state=https%253A%252F%252Fsecesx02vm38.ca.com%252Fsiteminderagent%252Fforms%252Foauth_ashish_facebook.fcc%253FSMQUERYDATA%253D-SM-MsRaZDsudf5YpQWhcPsd4CuUzCdbEhH0NQYqbjei5OIAdu3easUaR%25252fyyiqLiM8BWju1uyKiKZpMtFEF6sRkIH60kVOav8gJHqnEuGAmPhQetVor6HJXjA7nFlsGYqKgu6DgmxYTJqzGHjGSylvKwbvIxIz6uT%25252bWywh5Y31egA6WaFjn03D%25252bCseoRZHRhQ6LV%25252baK7lmXJ64pA%25252f3%25252fj5uohIb%25252fQZF%25252bsf92jKaHyURzKxEsHUwmkEhT4VcmX1SISu8fRaJ4Zxef%25252fA2t9IrLdgQY8RK6l5zs8EX2bdQQvlTc59yHAwZkpqZZx55JPe1BC1FMgH5%25252fZfTUvccWNNGfTt8mMiBH3fyKF862UFOjMWpdmVgO2DNnO65mG%25252bB75%25252fy3P91V%25252fTJcpGMcZuzLx3%25252fpwbbCFLQ2JTuquDL6BhPmX8Co7v3xprE2kE4e4BbfKr%25252fl2YzSmXjFcpuOesl%25252bXrs%25252femNoGj1TK%25252b8NWdmgX1DIdVdAd6BJvVrOM2LDdJKUEmMP%25252b5RPitFxdSTvv3qDQD3R2bO9isf2%25252be7DOUQsvBApWrfDRunvBaxyy1QUr67IUliAtng3V1esxrUVeHIc0EWxdA0XVQN1T48X9cTe5FXLHBZfRRZSaGlPPXIZ517ABAwd2q87dNm17pJ6Va4TlOhXnLFh97hzm%25252fcYuWakPiaQ0s0zVTLK6pgtwoDVOtuUzw2H9SrtUpcJ5RH%25252bP%25252bM9h8h%25252bXumlrZ1P%25252fbaC1LXTjAHktXcYBN7iVZ2v0OBC4QvspbfL8kM5B%2526SMOAuth_application%253Dsmuserfbapp2#_=_&display=page) and it works fine

The problem i am facing is:-

- When i open the authorization url in internet explorer 8, i get directed to a [HTTP facebook login url](http://www.facebook.com/login.php?skip_api_login=1&api_key=118285828341628&signed_next=1&next=https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?redirect_uri=https%253A%252F%252Fsecesx02vm38.ca.com%252Fsiteminderagent%252Fforms%252Foauthcb.fcc%253FSMQUERYDATA%253DSample&state=https%253A%252F%252Fsecesx02vm38.ca.com%252Fsiteminderagent%252Fforms%252Foauth_ashish_facebook.fcc%253FSMQUERYDATA%253D-SM-MsRaZDsudf5YpQWhcPsd4CuUzCdbEhH0NQYqbjei5OIAdu3easUaR%25252fyyiqLiM8BWju1uyKiKZpMtFEF6sRkIH60kVOav8gJHqnEuGAmPhQetVor6HJXjA7nFlsGYqKgu6DgmxYTJqzGHjGSylvKwbvIxIz6uT%25252bWywh5Y31egA6WaFjn03D%25252bCseoRZHRhQ6LV%25252baK7lmXJ64pA%25252f3%25252fj5uohIb%25252fQZF%25252bsf92jKaHyURzKxEsHUwmkEhT4VcmX1SISu8fRaJ4Zxef%25252fA2t9IrLdgQY8RK6l5zs8EX2bdQQvlTc59yHAwZkpqZZx55JPe1BC1FMgH5%25252fZfTUvccWNNGfTt8mMiBH3fyKF862UFOjMWpdmVgO2DNnO65mG%25252bB75%25252fy3P91V%25252fTJcpGMcZuzLx3%25252fpwbbCFLQ2JTuquDL6BhPmX8Co7v3xprE2kE4e4BbfKr%25252fl2YzSmXjFcpuOesl%25252bXrs%25252femNoGj1TK%25252b8NWdmgX1DIdVdAd6BJvVrOM2LDdJKUEmMP%25252b5RPitFxdSTvv3qDQD3R2bO9isf2%25252be7DOUQsvBApWrfDRunvBaxyy1QUr67IUliAtng3V1esxrUVeHIc0EWxdA0XVQN1T48X9cTe5FXLHBZfRRZSaGlPPXIZ517ABAwd2q87dNm17pJ6Va4TlOhXnLFh97hzm%25252fcYuWakPiaQ0s0zVTLK6pgtwoDVOtuUzw2H9SrtUpcJ5RH%25252bP%25252bM9h8h%25252bXumlrZ1P%25252fbaC1LXTjAHktXcYBN7iVZ2v0OBC4QvspbfL8kM5B%2526SMOAuth_application%253Dsmuserfbapp2&scope=email&response_type=code&client_id=118285828341628&ret=login&cancel_uri=https://secesx02vm38.ca.com/siteminderagent/forms/oauthcb.fcc?SMQUERYDATA=Sample&error=access_denied&error_code=200&error_description=Permissions%2berror&error_reason=user_denied&state=https%253A%252F%252Fsecesx02vm38.ca.com%252Fsiteminderagent%252Fforms%252Foauth_ashish_facebook.fcc%253FSMQUERYDATA%253D-SM-MsRaZDsudf5YpQWhcPsd4CuUzCdbEhH0NQYqbjei5OIAdu3easUaR%25252fyyiqLiM8BWju1uyKiKZpMtFEF6sRkIH60kVOav8gJHqnEuGAmPhQetVor6HJXjA7nFlsGYqKgu6DgmxYTJqzGHjGSylvKwbvIxIz6uT%25252bWywh5Y31egA6WaFjn03D%25252bCseoRZHRhQ6LV%25252baK7lmXJ64pA%25252f3%25252fj5uo), which doesnt open in Internet Explorer, with a message that "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage".
- Also When i paste the  [HTTP login url](http://www.facebook.com/login.php?skip_api_login=1&api_key=118285828341628&signed_next=1&next=https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?redirect_uri=https%253A%252F%252Fsecesx02vm38.ca.com%252Fsiteminderagent%252Fforms%252Foauthcb.fcc%253FSMQUERYDATA%253DSample&state=https%253A%252F%252Fsecesx02vm38.ca.com%252Fsiteminderagent%252Fforms%252Foauth_ashish_facebook.fcc%253FSMQUERYDATA%253D-SM-MsRaZDsudf5YpQWhcPsd4CuUzCdbEhH0NQYqbjei5OIAdu3easUaR%25252fyyiqLiM8BWju1uyKiKZpMtFEF6sRkIH60kVOav8gJHqnEuGAmPhQetVor6HJXjA7nFlsGYqKgu6DgmxYTJqzGHjGSylvKwbvIxIz6uT%25252bWywh5Y31egA6WaFjn03D%25252bCseoRZHRhQ6LV%25252baK7lmXJ64pA%25252f3%25252fj5uohIb%25252fQZF%25252bsf92jKaHyURzKxEsHUwmkEhT4VcmX1SISu8fRaJ4Zxef%25252fA2t9IrLdgQY8RK6l5zs8EX2bdQQvlTc59yHAwZkpqZZx55JPe1BC1FMgH5%25252fZfTUvccWNNGfTt8mMiBH3fyKF862UFOjMWpdmVgO2DNnO65mG%25252bB75%25252fy3P91V%25252fTJcpGMcZuzLx3%25252fpwbbCFLQ2JTuquDL6BhPmX8Co7v3xprE2kE4e4BbfKr%25252fl2YzSmXjFcpuOesl%25252bXrs%25252femNoGj1TK%25252b8NWdmgX1DIdVdAd6BJvVrOM2LDdJKUEmMP%25252b5RPitFxdSTvv3qDQD3R2bO9isf2%25252be7DOUQsvBApWrfDRunvBaxyy1QUr67IUliAtng3V1esxrUVeHIc0EWxdA0XVQN1T48X9cTe5FXLHBZfRRZSaGlPPXIZ517ABAwd2q87dNm17pJ6Va4TlOhXnLFh97hzm%25252fcYuWakPiaQ0s0zVTLK6pgtwoDVOtuUzw2H9SrtUpcJ5RH%25252bP%25252bM9h8h%25252bXumlrZ1P%25252fbaC1LXTjAHktXcYBN7iVZ2v0OBC4QvspbfL8kM5B%2526SMOAuth_application%253Dsmuserfbapp2&scope=email&response_type=code&client_id=118285828341628&ret=login&cancel_uri=https://secesx02vm38.ca.com/siteminderagent/forms/oauthcb.fcc?SMQUERYDATA=Sample&error=access_denied&error_code=200&error_description=Permissions%2berror&error_reason=user_denied&state=https%253A%252F%252Fsecesx02vm38.ca.com%252Fsiteminderagent%252Fforms%252Foauth_ashish_facebook.fcc%253FSMQUERYDATA%253D-SM-MsRaZDsudf5YpQWhcPsd4CuUzCdbEhH0NQYqbjei5OIAdu3easUaR%25252fyyiqLiM8BWju1uyKiKZpMtFEF6sRkIH60kVOav8gJHqnEuGAmPhQetVor6HJXjA7nFlsGYqKgu6DgmxYTJqzGHjGSylvKwbvIxIz6uT%25252bWywh5Y31egA6WaFjn03D%25252bCseoRZHRhQ6LV%25252baK7lmXJ64pA%25252f3%25252fj5uo) from the internet explorer window (which internet explorer could not display) in firefox i get redirected to the HTTPS login url and everything works fine.

Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: I'm using Google oauth, and seeing the same issue. Firefox 26.0 works, but IE 8 does not.